# Unparseable date: "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: java, mysql, date

I'm trying to send a date I picked with jDateChooser to a MySQL database, but it's giving me the following error:

```
Dec 30, 2015 5:23:29 PM werkstukcp3.swing.WerkstukGUI btnPatCreateActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

I've been looking around on StackOverflow in order to resolve this but everything I try just gave me another error.

I've got the following code for my button:

```
private void btnPatCreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int patientId = 12;
    String voornaam = txtPatVoornaam.getText();
    String achternaam = txtPatAchternaam.getText();
    int kamer = Integer.parseInt(txtPatKamer.getText());
    String departement = txtPatDep.getText();
    String campus = txtPatCampus.getText();

    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));

    Date parse1 = null;
    try {
        parse1 = sdf.parse(datePatAankomst.getDateFormatString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WerkstukGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.sql.Date aankomstdatum = new java.sql.Date(parse1.getTime());

    Date parse2 = null;
    try {
        parse2 = sdf.parse(datePatVertrek.getDateFormatString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WerkstukGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.sql.Date vertrekdatum = new java.sql.Date(parse2.getTime());

    Patient nieuwePatient = new Patient(patientId, voornaam, achternaam, kamer, departement, campus, aankomstdatum, vertrekdatum);
    PatientDAO.voegPatientToe(nieuwePatient);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: print out `datePatAankomst.getDateFormatString()` and `datePatVertrek.getDateFormatString()`, seems that one of them is `null`

Comment: seems you're parsing the date format rather than the actual date string itself...

Comment: Per Reimeus above, `sdf.parse(datePatAankomst.getDateFormatString());` Why are you parsing the dateFormatString rather than the date string?

Comment: @SiemenGijbels Please search StackOverflow before posting. You would have found hundreds of examples of working code to compare to yours. In the comparison you would have found the problem. Also, when you do post, cut the example code down to the absolute minimum needed to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Reimus pointed out, I was parsing the date format, rather than the actual date.

```
private void btnPatCreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int patientId = 12;
    String voornaam = txtPatVoornaam.getText();
    String achternaam = txtPatAchternaam.getText();
    int kamer = Integer.parseInt(txtPatKamer.getText());
    String departement = txtPatDep.getText();
    String campus = txtPatCampus.getText();
    Date aankomstdatum = datePatAankomst.getDate();
    Date vertrekdatum = datePatVertrek.getDate();

    Patient nieuwePatient = new Patient(patientId, voornaam, achternaam, kamer, departement, campus, aankomstdatum, vertrekdatum);
    PatientDAO.voegPatientToe(nieuwePatient);
}
```

This is working right now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Print value of datePatAankomst.getDateFormatString().Format of datePatAankomst.getDateFormatString() should match with format defined for sdf.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real Answer to your Question, but taking your first sentence literally, FYI…

## Don’t Bother Parsing

Actually, you do not need to parse a `yyyy-MM-dd` string to send to a database.

You should relay that value to the database via the [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class. The static [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) method takes that string format by default.